# Como verificar se o retorno Ajax está vazio

Tags: ajax

Estou tentando verificar um retorno JSon para uma tomada de decisão, mas não estou conseguindo, tenho isso:

```
if (sender.getFieldName() == 'IdUsuarioIntranet') {
    var MatriculaPessoa = sender.getValue();

    console.log("MATRÍCULA: " + MatriculaPessoa);

    $.getJSON(
        location.href, {
            IdPessoa: MatriculaPessoa
        },
        function(data) {

            if (data.CelularCorporativo == 'null') {
                console.log("VAZIO");
                data.CelularCorporativo = 'SEM CELULAR';
            }

            editors['CelularCorporativo'].setValue(data.CelularCorporativo);
            editors['EmailCorporativo'].setValue(data.EmailCorporativo);
        }
    )
}
```

Para ajudar na questão, quando retorno a busca pelo meu usuário eu tenho e-mail, mas não tenho celular, o e-mail é resgatado corretamente, mas como não tenho Celular cadastrado o campo Celular Corportativo precisa ser preenchido com um texto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas não está funcionando, alguma dica?

Comment: O que exatamente não está funcionando?

Comment: Olá @LuizFelipe, o console nem mostra o "VAZIO".

Comment: A requisição AJAX está sendo feita, pelo menos? Qual foi a resposta HTTP obtida?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é porque você está tentando comparar `data.CelularCorporativo` com 'null', mas colocou null entre aspas, e o javascript basicamente vai interpretar isso como uma string, não como nulo.

O correto seria

```
if (data.CelularCorporativo == null) {
    console.log("Vazio");
}
```

Ou simplesmente:

```
if (data.CelularCorporativo) {
    console.log("Vazio");
}
```

Nesse último caso qualquer valor que não seja null (vaizo), false ou 0 será considerado verdadeiro.

**Edit**

Essa resposta é válida se `data.CelularCorporativo` vier da API vazio e não com a string 'null'.

Comment: valeu, agradeço muito a sua dica.,